# passing dict value to BaseModel via Postman and OpenAPI in FastAPI

Tags: python, postman, fastapi, pydantic

I have frustrated with this problem I googled it and I didn't find a proper answer so decided to ask it here. I have  the following classes

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, BackgroundTasks, Body
from pydantic import BaseModel
import shutil
import datetime

class UserIn(BaseModel):
    username: str
    password: str
    family: str
    age: int
    height: float
    gender: bool

usr = UserIn(username='Bob', password='123456', family='Foo', age=21, height=169, gender=True)
```

and the following route method

```
@app.post("/uploadfile/")
async def create_upload_file(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, current_user: UserIn = Body(usr),
                         file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    background_tasks.add_task(send_video_for_process, file, current_user)
    return {"message": f"The {current_user.username} file {file.filename} uploaded"}
```

and the function is

```
def send_video_for_process(video: UploadFile, user: UserIn):
    content = video.file
    video_path = '/users/'
    path = video_path + user.username + video.filename
    with open(path, "wb") as buffer:
        shutil.copyfileobj(content, buffer) 
    return 'Done!'
```

When I don't pass anything the method pass `usr` correctly, but when I want to pass it with postman or \docs of Fastapi. I am getting the following error.

```
{
"detail": [
    {
        "loc": [
            "body",
            "current_user"
        ],
        "msg": "value is not a valid dict",
        "type": "type_error.dict"
    }
]}
```

the dictionary I put in postman is this `{"username": "Alice","password": "abcd1234","family": "Hey","age": 19,"height": 160,"gender": False}`

and here is a screenshot of my postman.

[image]

in the /docs I only change the value inside the schema but still get the same error.

[image]

I have added all libraries and I tried without `Body(...)` version. I played a lot with the dictionary but I got nothing.
I don't want to use `Form` or `Query`. I need the benefit of BaseModel in the future.

I use Mac and my server is `uvicorn`.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: I wish peeps wouldn't use screen shots because they are often broken depending on where and how SO is accessed, and screen shots can't be copy pasted as text either. If someone wants an answer I would have thought they could type in or at least copy / paste the text so it can be viewed properly. There probably should be a SO rule to close or delete questions with screen shotted text.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. The Postman screenshot shows you're using the form-data encoding for the body, which messes up with the path operation function definition which expects a json. You should use 'raw' to send directly json data.
2. You used `False` with a capital 'F' in the body, which is Python language and not compliant with json (need to write `false`), which may be the remaining cause of the error for OpenAPI.